# IZPACK exe wrapper + 7ZIP Installation error - java installer bundled

Tags: java, installation, izpack

Under Windows 7 64bit without pre installed JDK / JRE when I try to use a install package built with izpack, the following error happens when the target machine does not have a previous jdk installation and tries to install the bundled JDK (packed inside the installer package).

The install package was built with izpack5 + 7zip (seven zip)[image: after files extraction]

I didn 't figure with is a 7zip problem or a izpack problem.
7zip config file:

;!@Install@!UTF-8!
Title="SISNEG 1.0"
 
BeginPrompt="Instalar o SISNEG OFFLINE ?"
 
RunProgram="launcher-Win32.exe"
 
;!@InstallEnd@!

Launcher ini Config install file used by izpack exe wrapper:

**# Global en# Global entries, can be overridden by specific ones.**
 
jar = install.jar
 
download = http://www.java.com/
**# Win32 specific entries**

[win32]
 
jre = jre/jre-7u17-windows-i586.exe

Comment: just a wild question - there is a jre/jre-7u17-windows-i586.exe in the zip archive? That's kind of essential for the installer to work properly

Comment: Is this really SWT specific? If not, please remove the tag.

Comment: Yes. there is a jre inside this directory. This error is only under Windows 7 x64 or x86. Windows XP and windows 8 works perfectly. The config file and launcher.ini are in UTF-8 format. The installation do not hang or stop. It continues ok if alert ok button is pressed.

Comment: I stopped using izpack exe wrapper to call de JDK setup and bundled the already installed (or extracted not the jdk installer) JDK files. In the 7zip config file i put to call java -jar install.jar

Answer (score 0):

Bundle a previous jdk / jre installation (not the jdk / jre installer) and call the izpack app jar installer with the follwing 7zip config:

;!@Install@!UTF-8!
Title="SISNEG 1.0"
ExtractDialogText="Extraindo arquivos..."
BeginPrompt="Instalar o SISNEG OFFLINE ?"
GUIFlags="32"
**RunProgram="jre7\bin\javaw.exe -jar install.jar"**
;!@InstallEnd@!

packed insite de 7zip exe self extract is the jre folder.

I did not use the izpack exe wrapper.